# Confirmation Popup Linked to Custom Validator - Zend

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework, popup

Right now I have a form that adds an instance of `Dog` to an `Owner`.  I want to make it so that if the `Dog` already has an owner, a confirmation dialogue pops up.  I can get the confirmation to pop up everytime the button is pressed, but am not quite sure how to add the conditional to it.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid"> 
    <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <?php echo ctrlGroup($this, AddDogForm::KEY_DOG_ID, !($this->uberAdmin)); ?>

        <?php $addDog = $this->form->get(AddDogForm::KEY_ADD_BTN); ?>
        <?php $addDog->setAttribute("class", "btn btn-info"); ?>
        <?php $addDog->setAttribute('onclick', 'if (confirm("Are you sure?")) { document.form.submit(); } return false;'); ?>

        <?php echo $this->formSubmit($addDog); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

This will bring a popup up every time that the button is clicked, but I want it to check what's been typed before putting up the popup.

The following is my AddDogForm:

```
class AddDogForm extends Form{
const KEY_PROJECT_ID = "project_id";
const KEY_ADD_BTN = "project_add_btn";

public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()){
    parent::__construct($name);

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-inline');

    $id = new Text(self::KEY_DOG_ID);
    $id->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_DOG_ID);
    $id->setLabel("dogid to add");
    $this->add($id);


    $add = new Button(self::KEY_ADD_BTN);
    $add->setAttributes(array("id", self::KEY_ADD_BTN));
    $add->setLabel("Add Dog");
    $add->setValue("Add Dog");
    $this->add($add);   
    }


}
```

UPDATE:  I can add a custom validator by adding this to the AddDogForm:

```
public function hasNoOwner($dogId) {
    $drm = DogResourceModel::create();
    $dogs = $drm->find($dogId);  
    $dog = array_values($dogs)[0]; 
    if($dog->getOwnerId()){
        return false; 
    } else {
        return true; 
    }
}

public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
    $hasOwnerValidator = array(
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                    new Callback(
                            array(
                                    $this,
                                    'hasNoOwner'
                            )),
            ),
    );
    return array(
            self::KEY_PROJECT_ID => $hasOwnerValidator
    );
}
```

This will prevent the user from being able to input. Can I instead alter this so that it asks for confirmation rather than preventing the POST from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can add custom validator on post data on one of the field to validate against and then you can just show a general message.

There are two possible way you can achieve this.

1. add validator/custom validator based on your requirement on runtime in controller

   ```
   public function fooAction() {
       $form = new Dog_Form();
       if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
           // all post data is valid now we validate for dog/owner thing
           $form->getElement('star_tag')->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists',false,
              [
                  'table' => 'table name', 
                  'field' => 'field to check duplicate', 
                  'messages' => array('recordFound' => 'already_linked')
               ]
           );
           // redirect after successful insert
       }
       $this->view->form = $form;
   }
   ```
2. you can use isValidPartial method of zend form and do your validation over there. check http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.validate to see how it works.

Comment: I'm looking at the `addValidator` method, and it seems like you can add a custom validator, but the documentation doesn't seem overly clear on how to do so. Any tips?

Comment: You can add validators in following way

Comment: May be https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/custom-validators-in-zend-form/ will help you

Comment: So I got the validator working! However, it just prevents the POST operation all together. Is there a way to tie it to the confirmation?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. First time you show the error message, you can have some hidden value in your form so lets say "ignore".  so when user submits form first time, you add custom validator on runtime and show error. though you can have some sort of option available to user (something like ignore) when you show message. When user says ignore then you set some value in your hidden field and at that time you wont add you custom validator on runtime and will just continue with you normal post data validation. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Transmit variable `hasOwner` to view and add `onclick` if `hasOwner` is not empty.

```
<?php if (!empty($hasOwner)) $addDog->setAttribute('onclick', 'if (confirm("Are you sure?")) { document.form.submit(); } return false;'); ?>
```

If dog is selected in form, you can make ajax request to check for owner. Remove onclick attribute and add js code to check.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').submit(function() {
    var hasOwner = 0;

    $.ajax('/url/to/check', {
        'async':false,
        'data':{'dog':$('#<?php echo AddDogForm::KEY_DOG_ID; ?>').val()},
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success':function(data){
            hasOwner = data['hasOwner'];
        }
    })

    if (hasOwner) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) return true;
        else return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
</script>
```

`/url/to/check` should return json response if dog has owner

```
<?php
....
$hasOwner = hasOwner($_REQUEST['dog']); // function
echo \json_encode(['hasOwner'=>$hasOwner]);
exit;
....
?>
```

Comment: Well we don't know if there is an owner until we figure out the Dog that they are referring to.  In this case, it's a text box where they're typing the `Dog`'s id.  How can I check what they've typed when they hit the button before sending a post request?

Comment: Than you should make ajax request to server to check if selected dog has owner.

Comment: Since I'm using Zend to make the form, would I still be able to do that in the .phtml?  I guess I'm unsure of how I reference the text box